# Automation Using iframe

Tags: robotframework

As of now I am working on automation of iframes using Robot framework but I am not able to input text.

```robot
Current Frame Contains  xpath=//iframe[contains(@id,'sq-card-number')]  NONE

#Frame Should Contain   xpath=//iframe[contains(@id,'sq-card-number')]  Card Number

Wait Until Element Is Visible   xpath=//iframe[contains(@id,'sq-card-number')]  30sec

Input Text  xpath=//*[contains(@id,'sq-card-number')]   12345
```

The above is the code I used

Comment: where is your HTML? And what is the error you are getting? (this includes you do not get anything)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need select the iframe first with the [Select Frame](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Frame) seleniumlibrary keyword.

> Example:
>
> ```robot
> Select Frame      top-frame   # Select frame with id or name 'top-frame'
> Click Link        example     # Click link 'example' in the selected frame
> Unselect Frame        # Back to main frame.
> Select Frame      //iframe[@name='xxx']   # Select frame using xpath
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `driver.switchTo.frame("frameid");` and then try to use input text